# Unexpected error in Teamcity

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, msbuildextensionpack

I am trying to create a build agent (MSBuild) in Teamcity, but I am failing.

After I start a build process, I receive this error:

> [AssemblyInfo] C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\dbfd279ad4b719e0\projectpath\project.proj(146, 5): error MSB4018: unexpected error at AssemblyInfo-Task.
>    System.FormatException: The input string has a wrong format.
>
> at System.Version.VersionResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String argument)
>
> at System.Version.TryParseComponent(String component, String componentName, VersionResult& result, Int32& parsedComponent)
>
> at System.Version.TryParseVersion(String version, VersionResult& result)
>
> at System.Version.Parse(String input)
>
> at System.Version..ctor(String version)
>
> at MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.AssemblyInfo.UpdateMaxVersion(String& maxVersion, String newVersion) in c:\code\MSBuildExtensionPack\Solutions\Main\Framework\Framework\AssemblyInfo\AssemblyInfo.cs:Line 1206.
>
> at MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.AssemblyInfo.Execute() in c:\code\MSBuildExtensionPack\Solutions\Main\Framework\Framework\AssemblyInfo\AssemblyInfo.cs:Line 1089.
>
> at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>
> at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()

I hope that somebody can help me.

Comment: what does project.proj look like?